# Show that a function has minimum

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In a certain question I am asked to prove that the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a minimum. The function is $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} + x^2 + y^4$. It seems clear to me that $f(x,y) > 0, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. However, I have no idea of how to continue. The only thing I know is that $f(x,y) \leq \frac{1}{x^2} + x^2 + y^4$, and I don't know what does this imply. I don't want to know the points where the minimum is reached, but only how to prove that it necessarily exists.

Comment: Use the properties of continuous functions on compact sets

Comment: The $\frac 1{x^2+y^2}$ addend tends to infinity in a close neighborhood of $\{0,0\}$ and to zero in infinity. On the other hand, $x^2$ and $y^4$ vanish close to the origin and grow to infinity in infinity. Does that help?

Comment: But $\mathbb{R}^2 \ \{(0,0)\}$ is not compact

Comment: I already know those details. However, I don't know how to finish

Comment: @DanielC. Consider for example an compact annulus about the origin.

Comment: Oops, of course in [the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4793645/show-that-a-function-has-minimum#comment10192734_4793645) above I meant $(0,0)$, not $\{0,0\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then

$$f(x,y)=1/r^2+r^2+(y^4-y^2)\geq1/r^2+r^2-1,$$

so $f(x,y)\geq3$ when $r\geq2$ or $r\leq1/2$.

Note that $f(1,1)=5/2<3$, this means we only need to find the minimum for $r\in[1/2,2]$, and it must exist since $f$ is smooth on the compact set $r\in[1/2,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Fact 1. $f >0$ and $f(x,y) \to \infty$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$

Fact 2  $f(x,y) \to \infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$

Fact 3:  $f(x,y) \to
\infty$ as $|y| \to \infty$

Fact 4: $f$ is continuous.

Use these facts to show that $f$ has positive minimum.